# Computationally difficult [JavaScript] problem?

Tags: javascript, complexity-theory

I need a problem that is *computationally* difficult (in any language), that I can easily implement in JavaScript.  I'm trying to do a CAPTCHA-like test to make it unlikely that hacker is accessing my page mechanically.

Yes, I know that he *could* use Rhino or some other JS engine and do it -- that's why I want it to be computationally expensive, so it takes him a few hours to set up and his machine a few seconds to fake each access.

I'm think getting a bunch of large primes on the back end and sending over the product of two of them and demand that web-page factor it, but if anybody has a better idea, I'm all ears.  Also, does anybody have a good library for doing that factoring thing?

Comment: "CAPTCHA-like" but not CAPTCHA? Why?

Comment: @George Cummins It's a CAPTCHA for the *machine*, not the user ;-) [Takes a certain amount of time and "intelligence" to figure out. Although ... having a machine solve a CAPTCHA ... hmm.]

Comment: @George Cummins really? I hate captchas, they're so unimaginative

Comment: Is it supposed to take users a long time to figure this out too? Because there are plenty of CAPTCHA farms in developing countries that are full of people that are paid pennies per answer to type the answers to CAPTCHA style questions.  Also, any mathematical style question should be solvable by Google, fairly easily.

Comment: @pst: That was unclear to me, because of this statement: "to make it unlikely that hacker is accessing my page mechanically." If the OP is trying to avoid "mechanical" access, why build a "CAPTCHA for the machine"?

Comment: @Jaitsu: CAPTCHA's are annoying, but less so than forum spam and stolen data. They have the added benefit of meeting the need of something "that I can easily implement in JavaScript."

Comment: while(true); Infinite difficulty.

Comment: @George, true.. I'm not saying they're not useful - I believe in the idea just not the implementation. There are a lot of other methods to prevent automated spam bots

Comment: So if I browse your page on a mobile device (or any device with a slow CPU, or crappy JS engine) it's never gonna let me submit the form because of the computationally intensive task? :)

Comment: @JaniHartikainen -- not "never", just in a few seconds.  The user goes to my page, is shown some information I want him to see while his CPU does some math, then the browser submits the result and the user gets redirected to some other page.   @RyanBennett -- I need something where (a) it terminates and (b) I can verify he actually did the work.  @GeorgeCummins -- I'm guessing Google will *not* factor a 50-digit number for you.

Comment: hi there, I did read all the answers and comments but I still miss the purpose to check/verify there is cpu usage. I don't understand why It can't be done with other "cpu friendly" methods like suggested in the answers. can you please elaborate little further?

Comment: ok I get it now:-) interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same method as bitcoin, ie. reversing a secure hash.

Explained here:
http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/bitcoin-mining-make-money,3514-3.html

Bitcoin source
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

Comment: Yeah, that occurred to me about two months ago when I was teaching a class on Bitcoins.  You get the check-mark, since I forgot to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a standard captcha and make some more checking on the client side. for exaample, add a event listener on the captcha input text to listen for key down/key up events and xor the keycodes and send them along with the captcha. add a hidden input text in the form named email or something you find on every form. robots fill those up automatically. and if you get a value for post['email'] then it's a robot because the user won't see that. also you can have a piece of code in a totally unrelated javascript that automatically adds a field in the form that is required to validate. so...captcha no captcha, you can still enhance the robot protection client side without computation difficult processes.

Comment: You've completed inverted the point here: I don't want to check whether there's a real *person* there, I want to check if there's a real *browser* there.  I *need* it to be computationally difficult to discourage mass-roboting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that if it is known to be NP-Hard, it's going to be a pain in the rear for human beings to solve, as well, on non-trivial instances. Visual/auditory captchas are kind of cool in that they give people a leg up... we have very sophisticated sensory organs for processing these kinds of things, and computers are not too good at it (though they are getting better all the time!).

As such, you're probably better off coming up with a unique thing that people can do very easily, but that machines are not too good at. For instance, give some simple black and white pictures and ask the user which one doesn't belong, or show some pictures of foods and ask what kind of recipe you could make with them.

Comment: you're missing the point.  The human being is never going to *see* the problem.  I just want to make sure that the visitor's CPU burns a few billion cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Clever approach. Whenever one-way complexity is needed it makes me think of a hash. Simply hash some aspect of their user account (not anything sensitive) and send the hash to the client. You would want to truncate/pad the string to get your desired complexity level. This isn't to secure an account so md5 or any other hashing algorithm would be fine.

Here is some [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285901/implementing-brute-force-attacks-on-hash-values-in-javascript) that you might be able to leverage for the client side.

Comment: Also, see R C's answer for a real world application of this theory