# implementing brute force attacks on hash values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, brute-force, cracking

Before I get to the actual question I would like to clarify some things because I know how ridiculous "brute forcing with javascript" can sound when taken out of context :).

I'm working for my bachelor thesis at the end of which I aim to implement a proof-of-concept Javascript-based hash cracker. The idea is to work like this:
Users can submit a hash value along with information about the used algorithm. (Other) users can also click on a button on the website in order to participate in the cracking process. 
The server's task is to accept and split the submitted 'orders' into ranges, depending on the number of available workers. The ranges are then sent to the clients who clicked said button.

I am currently stuck with the two big questions of how to actually implement this brute force function.
So my main problem now is that, frankly, I'm not really that settled in Javascript yet. For starters, I would just use a hardcoded character set: alpha-numeric, lower and upper case, no special characters. Problem is I honestly have absolutely NO clue of how to actually implement the function that would try out al the character combinations, on how to program that. I can imagine using a normal array containing the charset, then two strings. One string would contain the range, the other will contain the tried combinations. So I would somehow have to iterate through the charset array and the strings maybe with cascaded for-loops or something, but I'm really stuck with the question of 'how' exactly :). I don't expect any of you to actually provide me with the full source code for such a function (unless you want to of course), but I'd really appreciate some hints or explanations on how to implement such a brute force function. I'd also not bother about performance or optimized coding at this point, but rather about comprehensive coding, or whatever you might want to call it :)

Sorry if I got fuzzy on some details in my question. If so, tell me and I will of course try to clarify further.

Comment: You might get a better answer on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: hm might be true, thank you - I've yet to look closer at what forums are in this stackexchange plattform here :). I'll repost there, but I hope it's OK if I leave this question here open, see what happens.

Comment: The second question should be on its own page - just remove it from here. If you want to know which possibilites you should run through, ask in the security forum. If you know which words should be generated, but not how, tell us what words that are.

Comment: ok good point, I took the part about the second problem out. What do you mean with "which words should be generated"? I know in general how brute force works: Basically to try out all possible combinations of characters taken from a given character set. My problem is I don't know how to implement this in terms of programming, in terms of 'what processes / actions could I use to perform this task'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force style function over an alphabet. There are probably easier ways to do this.

```
function brute(alphabet, match, int_start, int_stop){
    var a = alphabet, al = 0,                     // for alphabet
        m = match.toString(), ml = m.length,      // for our compare
        i = int_start || 0, j = int_stop || 0,    // range of numbers to test
        k = 0, l = 0, add = 0, sub = 0, diff = 0, // for building test string
        test = '', found = false;                 // test string and result

    if(i < 0) throw 'int_start must be at least 0';

    if(a.constructor !== undefined){           // We need a string or array as
        if( a.constructor.name !== 'String' && // our alphabet so we check for
            a.constructor.name !== 'Array' )   // correct input and modify if
                a = a.toString();              // necessary, or if we can't, 
    }
    else throw 'Bad alphabet type';            // we throw an error

    al = a.length;    // shorthand length

    add = al;                             // when i=0, we start prefix here
    while(add <= i - sub) sub += add,     // then work out what we have to
                          add = add * al; // prefix our number with

    diff = add - sub; // shorthand to save calculations

    while( i < j ){   // actual brute force loop starts here
        test = '';       // empty any previous string
        k = diff + i;    // convert our number from "x" to "1x"

        while(k > 0){           // build it as a string
            l = k % al;         // get index of digit
            test = a[l] + test; // add digit to string
            k = ( k - l ) / al; // move digits along
        }

        test = test.substring(1); // cut off the initial "1" we added

        if(test.length === ml && test === m){ // compare test to what you want
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        i++;                  // prepare for our next loop
        if(i - sub === add)   // and if we need another digit
            sub += add,       // then recalculate our prefix
            add = add * al,   // and then
            diff = add - sub; // update the shorthand 
    }

    // brute force ended, let's see what we've got

    if(found === false) i = -1; // if not found, return -1 as index

    return [i, test, m]; // index found, string found with, what we were looking for
}
```

Then use via e.g.

```
brute('0123abcd', '0c', 0, 20); // [14, "0c", "0c"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is the reason why I said written explanations or just hints would be nice - you lost me right after the exception is thrown - from there I ....I don't really understand what's going on here :). If you'd care to clarify a bit that would be seriously awesome. But in any case thank you for trying to help.

Comment: After the first exception - check the `type` of the input for the `alphabet`, if it's not a string, convert it to a string (because you can do array style things on strings). After second exception is the complicated bit - if you want to count (e.g. in binary, base 2) `0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111`, that is EASY but if you want to do `0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 000, 001, ...`, that is much more difficult. One way to do it is to work a base above (e.g. base 3), which is what I did. Then loop over integer => chars.

Comment: To make it check against hashes you would change the line `if(test.length === ml && test === m)` to check the hash of `test` against what you want to find (i.e. `if(myHash(test) === match)`)

Comment: It was bugging me then I noticed the method I did first was wrong (repeated itself in the middle) so I've changed it a LOT & added comments for nearly every line. New method prefixes an identity (1) on the front and then cuts it off so we get every outcome. @slagjoeyoco hope this is more helpful.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for adding the comments, very useful. Either it's my lack of coffee right now or I'm just plain stupid in terms of simple math, but after some thinking and fooling around with your code I'm left with two questions: 1) I now see what you're doing in the last if-check to find whether you need another digit or not, but: how on earth did you come up with this sourcery?! :) Is there an easier way to find this out? I mean, how did you know what these numbers will always play out? Sry for the confused question now but I really don't know how else to ask...

Comment: and 2) I guess IÄm still missing something here, but for what exactly do we need the prefix? Because the number of digits that are written depends on the number of loops in while(k > 0), which again depends on diff. So what's the prefix's purpose? Also, I see why you'd extract everything BUT the prefix out of the test string, but WHERE exactly is it actually added? From what I see, the prefix is calculated, but never actually added to the string, or is it?

Comment: The prefix is added here: `k = diff + i;`, rather than doing `k = i;`. It's purpose is to prevent combinations with preceeding zero-digits (such as `0001`) from being rendered as simply `1`. We know how to calculate the prefix because we know the alphabet size - the prefix needs to always be one digit longer than the number we are working with, and each time we do it, we need to start counting up from zero again, but luckily we know how long ago that was because it was our previous value of `add`. That we don't make these changes to `i` lets you "split the submitted 'orders' into ranges".

Comment: To explain the reason "we know how long ago that was because it was our previous value of `add`", think of the length of the current number (in our alphabet) as `j` then rather than just picking any `j+1` length number, we need to choose one which is one digit followed `j` (of the alphabet's) zeros, the most simple is the alphabet's `1`. Then this number gets reached by the current number exactly when the current number needs a new digit.

Comment: OK call me dumb but just when I thought I got it now I realize I sillt only understnad half of it :)...I see the purpose of adding the prefix to preserve some certain combinations. What I don't get is you say we do k = diff + i; to turn x into 1x, so to add the '1' right? Now, I played around with ti a bit and maybe it's jsut coincidence but k almost always ended up being anything but 1x. Also, if the prefix is added to k, why do we try to extract it from 'test' then? It's never actually added there, is it?

Comment: And in all of the test runs I did with this function I never noticed a difference between running it without adding a prefix and running it WITH adding a prefix - the resulting test string always matched...idk what I'm missing here, but there's definitely something. Thanks a lot for being so patient with heloing me so far though, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Set your alphabet to something basic like "012" or "ABC", and try to find "000" or "AAA" with and without the prefix.

Comment: Hm yes that explains it :D - without setting the prefix we need more tries because in some cases the test string is empty...I mean I get the purpose of the prefix (now more than ever), and also the general process of setting it is clear now, I guess I just have problems understanding how to know how to calculate it exactly, but oh well...

Comment: Say `j` is the length of the number `x` using your alphabet, then to calculate `prefix`, you could do `Math.pow( alphabetLength, j )`. This is `alphabetLength * alphabetLength * .. * alphabetLength`, `j` times, which you can do in a loop. Why do I use a loop in the code? Because each time we go a digit longer, we want to start from `0` again which means though `int_start` is mapped to `x`, it isn't actually `x` because it holds the information on how many digits we're up to, too ( `x = i - sub`, `k = prefix + x`, I call the "prefix" `add` in my code )

Comment: Hi - very sorry for my delayed answer. I now understand what you mean from your last explanation. Ture, int_start does hold the current start position which makes it possible for the function to work with any range. Thank you very much for your help and patience, I really appreciate it :)